# Example of the tidymodels for fine tuning is still running

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, tidymodels

I am new to the **tidymodels** package. I was trying to understand how to fine tune many models and I found an [example](https://www.tmwr.org/workflow-sets.html). I was running it and then at this [step](https://www.tmwr.org/workflow-sets.html#tuning-and-evaluating-the-models),

```
grid_ctrl <-
   control_grid(
      save_pred = TRUE,
      parallel_over = "everything",
      save_workflow = TRUE
   )

grid_results <-
   all_workflows %>%
   workflow_map(
      seed = 1503,
      resamples = concrete_folds,
      grid = 25,
      control = grid_ctrl
   )
```

The code keeps running and after **one hour and a half of running**, I get finally the results with the following messages:

```
x The workflow requires packages that are not installed: 'ranger'. Skipping this workflow.
! Fold01, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold01, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold02, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold02, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold03, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold03, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold04, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold04, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold05, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold05, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold06, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold06, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold07, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
! Fold07, Repeat1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `esti...
```

Is that normal that it takes so much time for running? I know there are 12 models for tuning and evaluating but I don't expect that it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

When rendering the book, we use GitHub actions and at the [end of this section](https://www.tmwr.org/workflow-sets.html#tuning-and-evaluating-the-models) we note:

> Using 3 workers in parallel, the estimation process took 1.6 hours to complete.

You shouldn't get those errors, though; be sure you have installed all the [correct versions](https://github.com/tidymodels/TMwR/blob/master/DESCRIPTION).

Comment: Indeed. I haven't see this information. Thank you

Comment: After installing the missing packages, I am still having the issue and I run the rest of codes in the documentation that says it takes less time and it's still taking 1.6 for running with the same issue. I wrote an issue on GitHub Tidymodels/tune.